# Firefox :before ignores positions

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have this input with some content defined in the `:before` tag. In IE and Chrome, it works perfectly, but Firefox makes a mess of it.

The content should be visible in the input tag, but in Firefox the content is visible in the `input-group-addon`.

HTML:

```html
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="input-group">
     <div class="iban">
        <input type="text" name="iban" class="form-control text-uppercase">
     </div>
    
     <div class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon"></span>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.iban:before {
  content: 'CH';
  color: #999;
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 7px;
  padding-top: 7px;
  z-index: 1000;
}
.iban > input {
  padding-left: 29px;
}
```

I reproduced it in a fiddle and I'm hoping someone faced this issue before and can help me out.

https://jsfiddle.net/9wme1roo/3/

Comment: You haven't given the pseudo element any position *values*...I'd start there.

Comment: Do you mean assigning a top value and left for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't given the pseudo element any **position values**.

```
.iban:before {
  content: 'CH';
  left: 0; /* add this */
  color: #999;
  position:absolute;
  padding-left:7px;
  padding-top:7px;
  z-index:1000;
}
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/0jbtrshu/)

Comment: Wow, wouldn't expect it to be that simple! Thank you so much!